# The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted

Tags: c#, docker, ldap

I am trying to access/authenticate user via ldap direcotry which is setup in docker but continously getting above error
https://github.com/wshihadeh/ldap_server
My code is as following

```
 LdapAuthentication ldap = new LdapAuthentication("LDAP://cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern");
                ldap.IsAuthenticated("LDAP://shihadeh.intern", "uid=developer", "developer_pass");

 public class LdapAuthentication
    {
        private String _path;
        private String _filterAttribute;

        public LdapAuthentication(String path)
        {
            _path = path;
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated(String domain, String username, String pwd)
        {
            String domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd, AuthenticationTypes.None);

            try
            { //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName =" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
                _path = result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public String GetGroups()
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
            search.Filter = "(cn =" + _filterAttribute + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
            StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

                String dn;
                int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

                for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
                {
                    dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

                    equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                    commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                    if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                    groupNames.Append("|");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " + ex.Message);
            }
            return groupNames.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any idea what could i be doing wrong.

Also tried with following code but getting error The LDAP server is
unavailable.

```
try
            {
                string username = "developer";
                string password = "developer_pass";
                string filter = "(&(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))" +
                     "sAMAccountName=username)";
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                LdapDirectoryIdentifier directoryIdentifier =
                   new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("LDAP://127.0.0.1/cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern", 389, false, false);
                using (LdapConnection connection =
                   new LdapConnection(directoryIdentifier, credentials, AuthType.Basic))
                {
                    connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 90);
                    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
                    SearchRequest search =
                        new SearchRequest(username, filter, System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Base, "mail");
                    SearchResponse response = connection.SendRequest(search) as SearchResponse;
                    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(entry.Attributes["mail"][0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

              
            }
```

If there is online running ldap free server available then i can try testing with it as well

Comment: Does your docker based ldap server running?

Comment: yes running. infact there is a UI provided in it from which i can login as well

Comment: i have even tried with docker container private ip then getting "The server is not operational." error  LdapAuthentication ldap = new LdapAuthentication("LDAP://172.18.0.2:389/cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern");
                ldap.IsAuthenticated("LDAP://shihadeh.intern", "uid=developer", "developer_pass");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code worked

```
try
            {
                // don't add LDAP://, the protocol is already known ...
                LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("127.0.0.1:389");
                // notice we don't use the domain here
                var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
                      "cn=developer,dc=shihadeh,dc=intern",
                      "developer_pass");

                // Apache Directory Server uses LDAPv3
                ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

                // 10389 is the plain port, no ssl needed
                //ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                // ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

                // let's not negotiate, only Basic is supported
                ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```